# How to convert 2k,1m,1g etc to 2000, 1000000 etc

Tags: java, android

Hello I'm new to java can anyone help me?

This code convert 
2000 to 2k and 1000000 1m etc

```
 private static final NavigableMap<Long, String> suffixes = new TreeMap<>();
    static {
        suffixes.put(1_000L, "k");
        suffixes.put(1_000_000L, "M");
        suffixes.put(1_000_000_000L, "G");
        suffixes.put(1_000_000_000_000L, "T");
        suffixes.put(1_000_000_000_000_000L, "P");
        suffixes.put(1_000_000_000_000_000_000L, "E");
    }

    public String format(long value) {
        //Long.MIN_VALUE == -Long.MIN_VALUE so we need an adjustment here
        if (value == Long.MIN_VALUE) return format(Long.MIN_VALUE + 1);
        if (value < 0) return "-" + format(-value);
        if (value < 1000) return Long.toString(value); //deal with easy case

        Map.Entry<Long, String> e = suffixes.floorEntry(value);
        Long divideBy = e.getKey();
        String suffix = e.getValue();

        long truncated = value / (divideBy / 10); //the number part of the output times 10
        boolean hasDecimal = truncated < 100 && (truncated / 10d) != (truncated / 10);
        return hasDecimal ? (truncated / 10d) + suffix : (truncated / 10) + suffix;
    }
```

I need a code which reverse the conversion for example 
2k to 2000 and 1m to 1000000

Comment: Replace the `k` with `000`? As in, `string.replace("k", "000")`?

Comment: ok Thanx for the help.

Comment: Not mentioned, but valid values could be `2k7` as well.

Comment: just replace is not an option.... because that will do a blind replace on strings...

Comment: @arminb no, it would be 2.7k.

Comment: what will be the best of how to that? can you tell me how to convert all values for example 1.2k to 1200 etc

Comment: @assylias Well `2k7` would be also a valid expression.

Comment: @arminb If the expression is generated by the code in the question then it would be 2.7k. But maybe the inputs come from a different source in which case you may be right.

Comment: Any solution plz help me? asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution just by storing the values in an ArrayList before converting and it worked osum. Thanks for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a solution. Need proper input as proper validations are not included. Let me know if it fits your need. also you can add/modify the switch cases according to your need.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String values[] = {
                "27",
                "999",
                "1.0 k",
                "110.6 k",
                "29.0 G",
                "5m",
                "5m30",
                "2.7k",
                "2k7",
                "2k17",
                "9.2 E",
                "9.2EE"
        };
        Test test = new Test();
        test.printValues(values);
    }

    private void printValues(String[] values) {
        for (String value : values) {
            if (isProperNumber(value)) {
                printValue(value);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not a proper number");
            }
            System.out.println("===================");
        }
    }

    private void printValue(String value) {
        String lastAlphabet = value.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]*$", "")
                                   .replaceAll(".(?!$)", "");
        long multiplier = 1L;

        switch (lastAlphabet.toLowerCase()) {
            case "k":
                multiplier = 1_000L;
                break;
            case "m":
                multiplier = 1_000_000L;
                break;
            case "g":
                multiplier = 1_000_000_000L;
                break;
            case "t":
                multiplier = 1_000_000_000_000L;
                break;
            case "p":
                multiplier = 1_000_000_000_000_000L;
                break;
            case "e":
                multiplier = 1_000_000_000_000_000_000L;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        String[] values = value.split(lastAlphabet);

        if (multiplier == 1) {
            System.out.println("" + values[0]);
        } else {

            double valueMultiplier = Double.parseDouble(values[0]);
            double valueAdder;
            try {
                valueAdder = Double.parseDouble(values[1]);
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                valueAdder = 0.0d;
            }
            double total = (valueMultiplier * multiplier) + valueAdder;
            System.out.printf("%.0f\n", total);
        }
    }

    private boolean isProperNumber(String value) {
        value = value.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        String count = value.replaceAll("[.0-9]+", "");
        return count.length() < 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to worry, just use simple JS Trick with Round figure up to 2 decimal places.

```
function somefunction(count){
    if (count >= 1000) {
        return Math.round((count/1000) * 10)/10+'k';
    } else {
        return count;
    }
}
```

if you want put more functionalities, just put more else if with devide 1000 with more million or billion, just 2 or 3 more else if makes your code better.

Answer (score -2):

```
private static final String dp(String value) {
    if (value.contains("k") || value.contains("K")){
        value.replace("k", "000");
        value.replace("K", "000");
    } else if (value.contains("m") || value.contains("M")){
        value.replace("m", "000000");
        value.replace("M", "000000");
    } else if (value.contains("g") || value.contains("G")){
        value.replace("g", "000000000");
        value.replace("G", "000000000");
    } ......


    return value;
}
```